# VS 2010 Class Designer not rendering relationships correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, class-design, class-diagram, class-designer

I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 Class Diagram designer and it does a nice job of showing relationships between a parent class and the classes that make up the properties of the parent. In the below sample, we can see that the **IFoo** interface has a property named **Bar** which is of type **IBar**.

[image: Sample created with the designer]

However, if I add existing classes, interfaces, etc... that were created outside the designer it does not show the relationships. See sample below...

[image: items added to designer that were not created using the designer]

The code is all the same; and correct; but the representation on the design surface is different. For existing classes, is there a way to instruct the designer to make the correct links without having to manually recreate the items using the designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to do it for the whole diagram, but I did find a *Property* level context-menu item (*e.g. **Show as Association***) which fixes it one Property at a time.